# Solving integral $\int _n^{2n}\frac 1x dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I want to solve the integral-

> $$\int _n^{2n}\frac 1x dx$$

From wolfram alpha I get it is $=log(2)\approx 0.69315$.

But I am unable to solve it step by step.So I need help.

Also,if the integral runs from $n+1$ to $2n$ instead of $n$ to $2n$ how do I evaluate the integral?

I am a beginner in calculus so an explanatory answer is going to be more helpful...

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: Do you know how to calculate $\int_{3}^5 \frac{1}{x} dx$?

Comment: Simples $\log (2n) - \log n = \log 2 + \log n - \log n = \log 2$.

Comment: The big hint from alpha is that you are using logarithms.  In particular, if you know the derivative of the log function, then the antiderivative of $1/x$ would be...

Comment: Please, show us what you tried, and where you got stuck. What is your knowledge on this subject? Provide a more detailed question for us, so that we can provide a more detailed answer for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since from differentiation, we know that $\frac{d}{dx}(\ln x)= \frac{1}{x}$ for $x>o$

Hence we can conclude that $\int \frac{1}{x} dx = \ln x + c$ where $x>o$ and $c$ is an integration constant.

So your problem reduces to $$\int_n^{2n} \frac{1}{x} dx = \left[\ln x + c\right]_n^{2n}= \ln 2n - \ln n = \ln 2 + \ln n - \ln n = \ln 2$$

Answer (score 2):

To address your second question:

$\displaystyle\int \limits_{n+1}^{2n} \frac{1}{x} dx= \log x]_{n+1}^{2n}=\log(2n)-\log(n+1)=\log 2+\log n-\log (n+1)=\log{\frac{2n}{n+1}}$

Unfortunately, this is all the simplification we can do. Note that $\log(n+1) \ne \log n+ \log 1 = \log n$

Comment: You could simplify to just $\log{\frac{2n}{n+1}}$, depending if your simplification is by argument or not.

Comment: True. I just meant simplification in terms of yielding a numerical substitution, like when the lower bound was $n$. Still, thank you for your input. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Notice:

- Assume $x>0$:
  $$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\ln(x)\right)=\frac{1}{x}$$
- Assume $a$ and $b$ are positive:
  $$\ln(ab)=\ln(a)+\ln(b)$$

---

$$\int_{n}^{2n}\frac{1}{x}\space\text{d}x=\left[\ln|x|\right]_{n}^{2n}=\ln|2n|-\ln|n|=\ln(2)+\ln|n|-\ln|n|=\ln(2)+0=\ln(2)$$